# How does this overcurrent indication circuit work?

Tags: transistors, dc-dc-converter

Can anyone explain how the overcurrent (OVC pin) circuit below works? I am lost in all these transistors. I only get that it will output +5V on the OVC pin in the event of an overcurrent condition on either the VPP or the VDD line, but have no idea how it actually does so.

[image: tl866 dcdc converter circuit]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Output voltage**

[image]

*Figure 1. R38 turns on Q11. Current flows to V<sub>DD</sub>.*

Note that the voltage out will droop as current increase due to R36.

**Current limit**

[image]

*Figure 2. When the voltage drop across R36 + D11 increases to about 0.7 V Q12 starts to turn on.*

Q12 turning on will steal the bias from Q11: the base of Q11 will be pulled high and it will start to turn off. This is the current limiter.

**Over-current indication**

[image]

*Figure 3. As Q11 turns off the voltage across its emitter-collector will increase.*

When Q11's V<sub>EC</sub> exceeds about 0.7 V Q14 will start to turn on and pass current through D13, etc., to indicate over-current.

The circuit seems to be intended to interface with 5 V logic.

- D13 & D10 prevent interference between the two circuits.
- R39, R40 and D14 form a 5 V voltage limiter for the logic interface.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at R36 in series with D11. The current flowing through them is approximately equal to the output current.

If the current increases, the VBE voltage of Q12 increases. At a certain point, Q12 will turn on, an this has a sort of chain effect:

- current flows through R38, the base of Q11 rises, Q11 increasingly turns off, limiting the output current
- since the output current lowers, presumably the output voltage lowers. Q11 is turning off, so its VEC voltage is increasing after all
- The VBE voltage of Q14 increases, so current starts flowing into D13
- The current charges C22 through R39, up to 5 V, limited by D14

A similar mechanism is in place for the VPP channel.

It is possible to estimate the ballpark of the cutoff current:

D11 Vf is approximately 0.5 V, assuming a Vgamma for the bjt of 0.7 V, we need 200 mV across R36 to turn on Q12. From the schematic R36 seems to be \$2\ \Omega\$, which is quite odd because this would give 100 mA of cutoff current, while the DCDC module is a 1.5 A part.

Comment: Anyway the schematic is difficult to read because it is not drawn very clearly, in my opinion. A transistor should be horizontal only if it is part of a pass gate or something of the sort, not if it is a current sensor.